# I cant create a stored procedure on DBeaver

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, dbeaver

I´m trying to create a package an inside a stored procedure for an Oracle database with Dbeaver, but Im getting the error:

```
the object JHON_HERNANDEZ doesnt exist
```

ON declaration:
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE JHON_HERNANDEZ
AS

elim_art (numero in char)

END JHON_HERNANDEZ;

Body:
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY JHON_HERNANDEZ
AS

create or replace procedure elim_art (numero in char) is
begin

```
dbms_output.put_line(numero);
```

end;
/

END JHON_HERNANDEZ;

Is there something wrong with the structure? its a Dbeaver bug?
I have this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7EMs.png)

I give secundary click and create a new package, this appears:
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY JHON_HERNANDEZ
AS
-- Package body
END JHON_HERNANDEZ;

When I try to compile it:
The object JHON_HERNANDEZ doesnt exist
Sql=Alter package JHON_HERNANDEZ compile, OriginalSql= Alter package JHON_HERNANDEZ compile, Error Msg= ORA-04043: the object doesnt exist

Please help me... i have several days on this

Comment: Did you create the package specification? Yes, I know, you *posted* its code, but - did you actually create it?

Comment: I´m new to DBeaver... how can I do that specification?

Comment: Literally execute the `CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE JHON_HERNANDEZ ...` block.

Comment: Well, I don't use dBeaver so I can't tell whether you're doing it right or wrong. But, the error you got says that as if you're trying to create a package body, while its specification doesn't exist. As you didn't post the whole body, check all appearances of JHON_HERNANDEZ. **However**: is that error (you posted) related to Oracle (so it has ORA-xxxxx error code), or to dBeaver? Maybe you're trying to do something in a wrong manner in the tool (dBeaver) itself?

Comment: I have updated the question with the result of trying to execute the block.

Comment: If you named the package JHON_HERNANDEZ, you can't END CAC_JHON_HERNANDEZ. Those names must match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was:
close the tab ... it asks if you want to persist and you say yes

Answer (score 0):

From the code in your question:

```sql
END CAC_JHON_HERNANDEZ;
```

If you named the package `JHON_HERNANDEZ` then the above line should be:

```sql
END JHON_HERNANDEZ;
```

In other words, it has to match the name of the package.

Also the name of the procedure in the package specification does not match the name in the package body.

If the code you posted in your question is your actual code, then try making the changes and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put the entire name of the package... i have made the update, thanks for your help. How do you create a package, can you describe or show an example?

Comment: @JhonHernandez have you read the Oracle database [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/index.html)?

Comment: I didnt had time, i was asked to do the stored procedure right away... if you know something, please, tell me

Comment: @JhonHernandez you could hire someone to do it for you.